# Can't add custom text and radio buttons do not work in rails 4 form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a text to a radio button in a rails 4 form, and to have my radio buttons be either the first or the second.
My form is:

```
   <%= form_for(@access) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :accessor_id%>
      <%= f.text_field :accessor_id %>
      <%= f.radio_button :can_read, 'read' %>
      <%= f.radio_button :can_edit, 'read and write' %>
   <% end %>
```

But the buttons just appear without text, and the user can click on both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call You radio buttons the same to be able to group them. In Your case it's not necessary to have 2 separate columns to describe the user rights, it will be easier to define a column access_rights which may have two values: read and read_write.

Then You can do this:

```
   <%= form_for(@access) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :accessor_id%>
      <%= f.text_field :accessor_id %>
      <%= f.radio_button :access_rights, 'read' %>
      <%= f.radio_button :access_rights, 'read and write' %>
   <% end %>
```